How to get all currency codes whether enabled or not in magento 2
Im trying to add custom atribute 'currency codes' by creating 'Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/PriceCrncyCodeAttribute.php'.
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class PriceCrncyCodeAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $storeManager;
    private $appState;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        State $appState,
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->appState = $appState;

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        try {
            $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            // Area code is already set, so no action needed
        }

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'price_crncy_code',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Currency Code',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'backend' => '',
                'sort_order' => '30',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'default' => null,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'group' => 'General',
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'option' => array('values' => ['want to add all currencycodes here'])
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'price_crncy_code');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}z
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}

i want to set all currency codes as options for this select tag

You can getConfigAllowCurrencies() from Magento\Directory\Model\Currency:

private $currencyModel;

public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    State $appState,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currencyModel
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->appState = $appState;
    $this->currencyModel = $currencyModel;
}

(...)

'option' => array('values' => $this->currencyModel->getConfigAllowCurrencies())

